# zoo extension broke, are there any alternatives?

Tags: extensions, zoo

I was asked by a friend to take a look at the **zoo** extension, which broke. It was used for displaying photographs.

I have never worked with any CMS, so this is a different world for me. I cannot update the **zoo**, since the license has expired. And my friend does not want to extend it.

So is there any free alternative to **zoo** extension for displaying photo and video content with some text?

And would it be possible to connect the same database from the zoo for that alternative extension in order to transfer quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a current Zoo subscription to update. Zoo is free. It's the apps (product catalog, cookbook, documentation ...) that require a subscription, but you can update the core for free and continue using your apps. In addition, it is a good time to update since Yootheme is working together with Zoolanders in the new ZOO 4